# Override plugin output in Joomla! 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is there a way to override plugin output? I want to override the Phoca Gallery plugin to use `<ul><li>` instead of `<div>`'s.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Phoca Gallery output (templates) is written in Joomla! MVC pattern so it can be overriden by template.

You need to copy in your template directory HTML this file: phocagallery.php

Then edit for example `$output .= '<div class="detail" style="text-align:right">';`

to `$output .= '<ul class="detail" style="text-align:right">';`